# Python Thread subcalss: __init__ not called

Tags: python, python-multithreading, subclassing

I'm currently trying to write my own subclass of `threading.Thread`. However, it seems that the `__init__` call to the subclass does not work, because I always get an `AttributeError` in the `run` function when I want to address my own class variables with `self.x`.

Here is my code:

```py
class MonitoringWorker(threading.Thread):
    def __int__(self, threads_hashtag: int = 1, threads_image: int = 4, threads_user: int = 1):
        self.threads_hashtag = threads_hashtag
        self.threads_image = threads_image
        self.threads_user = threads_user

        self.queue_hashtag = Queue()
        self.queue_image_meta_first = Queue()
        self.queue_image_meta_second = Queue()
        self.queue_image_meta_third = Queue()
        self.queue_user = Queue()
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        workers_hashtag = [HashtagWorker(self.queue_hashtag, self.queue_image_meta_first, i) for i in range(self.threads_hashtag)]
        # do stuff


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MonitoringWorker()
    m.start()
    m.join()
```

Can some explain the behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo `__init__` and not `__int__` :)

Comment: thanks it seams to be to late... I am googleing for over an hour